# How to inverse a number without using array or any arithmetic operations

Tags: c++, c

How can I reverse a number without using arrays or any arithmetic operations i.e from 85 to 58. Using bitwise operators might be the solution. But what series of operations are needed to reverse a number. I've tried shifting and complementing.

And is there a way to get binary or hexadecimal as input and perform operations on it. Rather than getting int and typecast at printf?

Comment: You can use recursion if you know how to get last digit.

Comment: What are "arithmetic operations"? Multiplying by 2? Shift by 1? Xor?

Comment: Arithmetic operators are + - * / %
Bitwise operators & | ~ ^ << >>

Are you confused about that?

Comment: Not at all. Your reply makes clear which operators are considered allowed.

Comment: How do you get the input? Where do you store it? Have you written any code?

Comment: I tried a circular shift. But circular only works on some numbers like 54
i.e. 110110 shift by 1 gives 101101
Same is not true for many numbers.

I tried long and CHAR_BIT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after all. Using the right shift 8 times and left shift 2 times would work on a 2 digit number. And follow the shift bits for different digit numbers,

Answer (score 0):

there are alot of api's to do that // but the easiest way use a stack :D or convert it to string then it will be such as array you can inverse it easilly

Comment: Is there a way to do it just with int or long. String means char array.